# Mbed ransomware attack on my PC

Tags: windows-10, security, encryption, virus, ransomware

My pc attacked by Mbed ransomware virus and all files get encrypted.

[image]

To kill this virus, I have scanned my full system with bootable anti-virus
and used Emsisoft Decryptor to decrypt files.

[image]

But this tool, can't able to decrypt even a single file.

So what are other ways that exist for me to decrypt my PC files?

Comment: If any random software one can download from the net could decrypt then it wouldn't be much point for encryption, would it? Your data is lost unless you pay - and you absolutely shouldn't - and the system is compromised and shouldn't be used, period. Someone coding should know this things, BTW.

Comment: @Siddharth the best defense against ransomware is regular backups. I'm guessing you haven't recently backed up your data?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It’s not that clear-cut. Many ransomware trojans are badly made and the encryption is reversible. That’s why these decryptors exist and trying them is definitely a good idea.